# Change time format using TryParseExact()

Tags: c#

```
            char[] delimiterChars = { '/' };

            DateTime loanRequestFromDate;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lbl_RequestFrom.Text))
            {
                string loanRequestFromDateStr = lbl_RequestFrom.Text;
                string[] t = loanRequestFromDateStr.Split(delimiterChars);
                loanRequestFromDateStr = t[1] + "/" + t[0] + "/" + t[2];
                loanRequestFromDate = DateTime.Parse(loanRequestFromDateStr, new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
            }

            else
            {
                loanRequestFromDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
```

I'm now using this way to for the FromDate. But I want to replace using TryParseExact()

Comment: What don't you understand about using TryParseExact?

Comment: `TryParseExact` is for specifying the format of a date string that you're parsing to a `DateTime`. `DateTime` is a 64-bit numeric value and has no format until you convert it to a formatted `string`.

Comment: Recommended to have a read on [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0). The doc provides the usage example.

Answer (score 1):

`TryParseExact` requires specifying exact formats. For example, you have a special format as part of the file name. Lets say something like `ssmmhhyyddMM`. No way any existing standard provider can parse it. This is where you would use `TryParseExact`

```cs
DateTime d
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("301209200111", "ssmmhhyyddMM", new CultureInfo("en-US", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    Console.WriteLine("TryParseExact: Parsed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("TryParseExact: Not Parsed");
```

Using `TryParse` is pretty simple for any standard data type

```cs
DateTime d;
if (DateTime.TryParse("12/13/2020", new CultureInfo("en-US", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Parsed");
        
        
if (DateTime.TryParse("13/12/2020", new CultureInfo("en-US", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Parsed");
        
if (DateTime.TryParse("13/12/2020", new CultureInfo("fr-Fr", true), DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Parsed");
```

Results

> TryParseExact: Parsed
> Parsed
> Not Parsed
> Parsed