# C# DateTime.TryParseExact over date without dots

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have following code:

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyMMDD", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out var date)
```

and my test string is like 210201. It keeps failing.
When I tried

```
DateTime.ParseExact("201101","yyMMDD",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it throws error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [#72694814](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72694814/change-time-format-using-tryparseexact)

`format = "yyMMdd"`

Answer (score 4):

The correct [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) is `yyMMdd` (note small `d` instead of capital `D`):

```
// 01 November 2020
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("201101","yyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W3WulW)